# How to build a docker image on top of Jelastic jelastic/nginxphp?

Tags: php, nginx, jelastic

For local development I try to build a docker image on top of jelastic/nginxphp as suggested in https://docs.jelastic.com/building-custom-container/ . Unfortunately I can not see any server (php-fpm or nginx) once I start the image.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 jelastic/nginxphp:1.14.2-php-7.2.9
```

```
➜  ~ curl 127.0.0.1:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I can see that systemd gets started, but I do not see php-fpm or nginx.

```
➜  ~ docker exec 55a454cf01ad ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 191276 10172 ?        Ssl  07:58   0:00 /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
root         9  0.0  0.0 200788 10408 ?        Rl+  Nov25   0:00 /usr/bin/ps aux
```

I wonder how to build my app on top of this image. Is there any documentation or is there an example for `jelastic/nginxphp`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the jelastic/nginxphp docker image is built in a quite different way from, for example, the Nginx repo from the Docker library - that's because it was designed to be launched on Virtuozzo DevOps platform and have the support of all the functionality and automatizations provided there.

If you run
`'docker inspect jelastic/nginxphp:1.14.2-php-7.2.9'`, you can see

```
    "Cmd": [
        "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"
    ],
```

To run the image locally, you need to override the CMD during launch

```
docker run -p 8080:80 jelastic/nginxphp:1.14.2-php-7.2.9 /usr/sbin/nginx '-g daemon off;'
```